# C# Family Class Design

Tags: c#, class-design

I am working on building a single family unit (class) for an application. I've done some searching and found solutions for entire family trees, but this app doesn't care about anything outside the single family unit which is defined as (Father, Mother, Child1, Child+n)

This application is about the children (activities they can do based upon age and skill levels), but needs references to the parents.  The parents are only needed for reporting purposes and are required to have driver's license and insurance on file.

The application is being built using C# & EF Code First.  None of the database annotation elements have been added to the class yet as that isn't the problem.

Below are my classes.  The main business rule state that each sibling will have his/her own record, but they need to be linked together so only one mailing (electronic or snail) is sent, if the parents live together.  If the parents are divorced, then two letter (or emails) need to be sent.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

public class Youth : Person
{
    public string CurrentGrade { get; set; }
    public Adult Mother { get; set; }
    public Adult Father { get; set; }
    public Adult ICE { get; set; }

    public virtual Adult Adult { get; set; }
}

public class Adult : Person
{
    public string DriversLicense { get; set; }
    public string StateIssued { get; set; }        
    public string AutoInsuranceCarrier { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumer { get; set; }

    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

The logic pattern I was stuck in was that siblings will have the same AddressId.  That failed when I applied the divorced parents, each having one child at their address. As far as mailings go, it would work because they are at different addresses. It doesn't feel like the best design.  If this were handled by UI, then it would work.

My next thought was to create a Family class and add each family member to it.  In this instance, the user would have to make the selection of which people would be living at which address.

```
public class Family
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Person;
}
```

That also doesn't seem like the best solution.  I feel there is a better design.  I just cannot find it on my own.

Are there any pitfalls to one of these approaches that I'm not seeing yet?
Can someone point me in a better direction?  And explain why that direction is better?

Thanks in advance for all your insights!

Comment: Imho, composition is better than inheritance in this case. Because you are dealing with EF, you can created DB scheme first, and then, based on the scheme create your own classes.

Comment: Would the application need to support an instance to transform from one type, say youth, to another type, say adult? Also Adults have parents too. There is no right or wrong here, a lot depends on use.

Comment: As a design question this is probably better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Emo In this instance, the youth will 'age out' of the program when s/he turns 21.  The youth could be promoted to an Adult, but wouldn't participate in the activities any more.  I think you are correct.  I'll need to include a way to 'promote' the youth to an adult.  Thanks.

Comment: @AlexFoxGill when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat it's merely an observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to keep your models flowing as you would think about them.

For instance, I would not have an Address class that contains Person.  I would have an Address class containing only base data about the Address.  In Person, I would have an Address.  This fits with the "Person lives at this address" and will likely fix your who-lives-where issue.  This is the type of setup you have for "Vehicle"

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  I don't know why I didn't see it before.

Answer (score 2):

The "Father", "Youth", "Brother", etc... is not attribute of the person, but attribute of relationship between persons. One person can be both "Father" and "Brother" and "Uncle".

Better design is something like this (i don't know all your requirements):

```
public class Person {
    public Name{get;set;}
    // etc...
    public List<Relationship> Relationships{get;set;}
}

public class Relationship {
    public Person P1{get;set;}
    public Person P2{get;set;}
    public RelationshipKind Kind{get;set;}
}

public class RelationshipKind {
   // for example: Father
   public Name1 {get;set;}
   // for example: Child
   public Name2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry, Why did you change "Father" to "Farther"?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into details regarding whole design, I will focus only on the address issue.

I recommend that you have your address class defined in a way that it does not have navigation property back to a person:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }    

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

}
```

Then I would link your `Adult` (or even `Person`) class to Address like so:

```
public class Adult : Person
{
    public string DriversLicense { get; set; }
    public string StateIssued { get; set; }        
    public string AutoInsuranceCarrier { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumer { get; set; }

    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public int AddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

With this approach, if parents are not divorced, they can share the same address instance. In case they are divorced, your application has to set different address for one of the parents. In case you need to find people living under same address, you can do sth like this:

`_dbContext.Persons.Where(p => p.AddressId = addressId) ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of States then you can use that in a lot of places: DriversLicenseState, AddressState, InsuranceState etc.  If this isn't a blank string then you don't have to validate the user input and can just put a drop-down on the application.

String current grade.  If you instead enter the year the child entered first grade then you don't have to manually update this every year; it can be calculated - though you also have to include an int for NumberOfYearsHeldBack.  But its less work to update that int once in a great while, than update every student every year.

Personal Preference: I like 'NameLast' and 'NameFirst' rather than 'FirstName' & 'LastName' just because it means these properties will bunch together alphabetically in all the IDE drop downs etc, just like AddressID, Address1 and Address2

You might consider making 'Mother' into a nullable 'Mother?' and the same with 'Father' to 'Father?'.  Some kids simply don't have both parents.  If you want to be politically correct you might consider 'Parent1?' and 'Parent2' and put an enum on the relationship to select mother, father, guardian because some kids have 2 moms or 2 dads or their older brother is their legal guardian.

In your address class why is there a person property when you already have a PersonID property? For that matter why does the address have a personID at all?  This only needs to be one-way.  A person has an address, but an address doesn't have a person.  This way you can have 5 people all with the same address.  If you try to keep both synchronized two-way it will get fouled up, not to mention you have to have a List<> of personID inside the address. Since address is a type, add another one to each person so you have an AddressPhysical and AddressMailing. Now you can have 4 kids each with different places they sleep but they all get their mail at grandma's P.O.Box.

I wouldn't add a third adult to the child as their ICE.  Instead I would make a List<> of adults (its just going to be a list of ID ints really) That way you can keep working down the list in an emergency until you reach someone.